# Create drop down menu that queries mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Let me explain further exactly what I am trying to do. I am querying a database with one table with fields id, book, author, genre, email.

I have an insert page that works fine but I need to have a search page that has 4 searches with a drop down box showing unique entries for each field - book, author, genre, email.

I have come across a URL that I have got working to show entries in database but when you click on an entry it goes nowhere:
<s>`http://www.phpsuperblog.com/php/html-form-drop-down-menu-with-data-from-mysql-datebase-as-options/`</s>(deadlink)

I hope I am doing something basic wrong. Latest attempt to have it working is here:
<s>`http://swapabook.hostei.com/search6.php`</s>(deadlink)

I had been previously trying following the following link to create these drop down menus to query what is dynamically changing in a database:
<s>`http://forums.devarticles.com/mysql-development-50/drop-down-menu-populated-from-a-mysql-database-1811.html`</s>(deadlink)

I hope I'm doing the correct thing by editing this but if you want me to add a new entry I can also do this.

My html code is as follows:

```
 <form action="namesearch2.php" method="post">
   Name of Book
   <SELECT NAME=name>
      <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
   </SELECT>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The php is as follows:

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect('mysql1x.000webhost.com','a4425533_swapabo','xxxx','a4425533_swapabo');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"'SELECT book FROM book'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $bookselect=$row["book"];
  $options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$bookselect\">".$bookselect.'</option>';
  }
?>
```

I previously had it that you could enter text in a field and it would query the database but I'm having trouble complicating it further by trying to populate this drop down menu.

<s>`http://swapabook.hostei.com/search2.html`</s>(deadlink)

Comment: check my answer below, I guess it has the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/15160649/348311

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to what user2035638 said ..

I inspected your HTML .. and found that the first entry is not closed.

```
Name of Book
<SELECT NAME=name>
  <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
    </SELECT>
<input type="submit">
```

You have to close the first `<OPTION>` so that your code should look like this:

```
Name of Book
<SELECT NAME=name>
  <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
<?php 
 $con=mysqli_connect('mysql1x.000webhost.com','a4425533_swapabo','xxxx','a4425533_swapabo');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT book FROM book",$con);
?>
<form action="namesearch2.php" method="post">
   Name of Book
   <SELECT NAME=name>
      <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
      <?php  
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $bookselect=$row["book"];
      echo "<OPTION VALUE=\"$bookselect\">".$bookselect.'</option>';
      }
     ?>


   </SELECT>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I made the changes mentioned but I get an error "Choose PHP Error Message warning:mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ...search3.html on line 14. Files amended are http://swapabook.hostei.com/search3.html and PHP code here <?php
$con=mysqli_connect('mysql10.000webhost.com','a4425533_swapabo','sch00ner','a4425533_swapabo');

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"'SELECT book FROM book'");

?>

Comment: You can use mysql instead of mysqli

Comment: Edited the code but same warning with mysql rather than mysqli

Comment: Pro Tip: When the option's `value` is the same as its text, then you can safely remove the `value` declaration.  Javascript and html form submission behaviors will all continue to work normally.

Answer (score -2):

There seems to be one error in your code:

This line:

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$bookselect\">".$bookselect.'</option>';
```

Change to:

```
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"".$bookselect".\">".$bookselect.'</option>';
```

Comment: I was about to note the same!

Comment: That doesn't matter cause double quotes could be parsed for variables.

Comment: @Hast: You mean: variables within double quotes will be parsed? Indeed.

Comment: I added that /OPTION in the html code and I also changed that entry above but still seeing the same thing.

Comment: Also if I run the php directly on the site I get following: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/a4425533/public_html/namesearch2.php on line 15 but not sure that is a valid troubleshooting step anyway

Comment: @user2123867: What does line 15 look like?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel line 15 was the change suggested above

Comment: @daithi_dearg It is incorrect and you don't need the change. For the record, the correct syntax would be `$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"".$bookselect."\">".$bookselect.'</option>';` (note the exchanged `"` and `.`).

Comment: @marcelkorpel Made the change but still get the same error "Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/a4425533/public_html/namesearch_mk.php on line 12" which is the line I changed. Updated html is at http://swapabook.hostei.com/search_mk.html

Comment: @daithi_dearg: Is *that* the error you get? You didn't mention that in your question. Please update it accordingly. Can you add a `var_dump($result)` after your query and if it's `FALSE`, please add an `echo mysqli_error($con)` after the query.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel Thanks for pointers but I got around this be following http://www.phpsuperblog.com/php/html-form-drop-down-menu-with-data-from-mysql-datebase-as-options/. Thanks for your efforts.